# How to create a mixed authentication for Firebase in Android Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a mixed authentication for my firebase storage.  The public section would have general access to common items like photos, and private one (after authentication).  However, even after setting my rules, my Android studio project is denying access to even the public items.  My AndroidManifest has access to internet permission. My firebase rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /purchasers/{email}/images {
      allow read,write :if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
    match /public/images {
      allow read,write :if request.auth == null;    
    }
  }
}
```

The code that I'm using to access Firebase storage is this:

```
 fun getPublicImages(): MutableList<String> {
    val imageList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val fbStorage = Firebase.storage
    val imageRef = fbStorage.reference.child("/public/images")
    Log.d("PurchaserViewModel", imageRef.path)

    imageRef.listAll()
        .addOnSuccessListener { (items) ->
            for (item in items) {
                imageList.add(item.path)
                Log.d("PurchaserViewModel", item.path)
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener( ) {
            Log.d(TAG, it.message.toString())
        }
    return imageList

}
```

The purpose for this function and public access to /public/images folder is because I'm
using it for a user registration page in my app where the user can select a temporary
icon until user logs in.  Once a user logs in, he will be able to access the
/purchasers/{email}/images folder after authentication. The part of the documentation
that I'm trying to follow is: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#public.  The funny part
is that access is granted in the rules playground
for unauthenticated public access, but it is denied when my app tries to access it.

Comment: To [allow public access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#mixed_public_and_private_access) use `allow read,write: if true;` or `allow read,write;`. Note that that allowing public **write** access is big security, as it allows anyone who has your configuration data to use your bucket for their own purposes.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for replying.  Well I made the change that you suggested, but unfortunately it still shows the same error message.  I've even changed it to match /public/images allow read;  My logcat message is: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnsFOFM6YEPJqKZXQaab58clkgYYlg?e=Gk0xVc

Comment: Don't tell me what you changed, but update your question to show the latest rules.  That's also a great moment to remove anything that is not relevant, such as the match and rules on `purchasers`: since you're not reading from that in the code, that part of your rules isn't relevant to the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example.